# installed postegres on but it says not installed

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install postgres on my ubuntu machine following this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-14-04

I can create new users,  use the psql command. But when I run postgres -v I get the error:

The program 'postgres' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install postgres-xc

The other day i was trying to check if I have libxml2 but I had to chekck another way? perhaps the case is the same with this? im not sure...

Comment: Presumably the `postgres` server binary isn't on the `PATH`. You don't usually have to run `postgres` manually so this isn't a problem. If you're just trying to check the version use `psql --version` or `SELECT version();`.

Comment: I have added postgreSQL apt repository first in my system and re did everything. I was just trying to get the 'postgres -v' to work but as you mentioned it isnt a problem I just needed to check if postgres was installed and 'psql --version' works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1: Add PostgreSQL Apt Repository**

PostgreSQL packages are also available in default Ubuntu repository, But when I try to install PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 12.04 I only found PostgreSQL 9.1 was in default apt repository. So I request you to add PostgreSQL apt repository first in your system suggested on official PostgreSQL website using following command.

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
$ wget -q https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

**Step 2: Install PostgreSQL**

Now as we have added PostgreSQL official repository in our system, First we need to update repository list. After that install Latest PostgreSQL Server in our Ubuntu system using following commands.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

**Step 3: Connect to PostgreSQL**

After installing PostgreSQL database server, by default it creates a user ‘postgres’ with role ‘postgres’. It also creates a system account with same name ‘postgres’. So to connect to postgres server, login to your system as user postgres and connect database.

```
$ sudo su - postgres
$ psql
```

Now you are logged in to PostgreSQL database server. To check login info use following command from database command prompt.

```
postgres-# \conninfo
```

To disconnect from PostgreSQL database command prompt just type below command and press enter. It will return you back to Ubuntu command prompt.

```
postgres-# \q
```